# Share a single variable (DWORD) across all users and AppDomains in Windows

Tags: c++, windows

I need to communicate a single DWORD across all the users on the computer.  All the users will be using my DLL but may have different levels of security.

Is there anything lightweight I can do here?  I'm was thinking a Global Atom, but that doesn't allow me to communicate the handle.  Named mutex are also global too, but again I can't share the DWORD via it.

I suppose I could do a MemoryMapped file but that's a lot of 'code' just for a single number.  (I'm using C++)

I am missing something?  Can I actually use ATOMs?

thanks

Comment: It will not be any easier just because it's a single variable. What is the variable?

Comment: Just a process id

Comment: Sounds like a security risk.

Comment: How often and under what circumstances does the value change?  Could you use a registry value?

Comment: Yeah, I thought of using the registry... Since the Setting of the value is done in a service with local system access I could use hklm and then the readers could open it with read access.... It just seems so heavy handed.